# SQL Loader quit working on new computer

Tags: sql-loader

I was successfully loading csv files using SQL*Loader. After getting a new computer, the files no longer load. I'm using the same batch and control files. When I run the batch file, a command prompt screen flashes on the screen, but I don't get any error message.

Comment: Open the batch file in Notepad. Open a command prompt. Run each command from the batch file in that command prompt, one after the other. What do you see as a result of the commands? You've provided zero details here that will help us to help you. You need to provide specifics. We know nothing about what changed between your old and new computers. You do.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the 12.1 client on your new machine you could be affected by bug 17505478.

"Executing sqlldr.exe from 12.1 Client fails with error :'oraodm12.dll is missing from your computer'"

You may need to get this file from Oracle support and put it in the bin folder of your install.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered with the same issue and updated the version of SQL Instant Client. 
**SQL instant client** is required to run **SQL loader** using CMD (Refer [SQL Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html) Page to download). 
I have used **Version 19.3.0.0.0** of SQL instant client and it works perfectly fine.

Follow below steps to do setup on machine:

1. Download [Instant Client Basic](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html#license-lightbox) package.
2. Download [Instant Client SQL*Plus](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html#license-lightbox) package.
3. Unzip these two clients and place in your drive.
4. Update PATH in environment variable for these two clients.
   [image: Instant Client in PATH environment variables]